# Automated reply issue on Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a job portal and incorporated 'Contact Form 7' to apply for the job. On the "To" field, I have employer email address "employer@gmail/yahoo/whatever.com" and "From" field "[your-name] <no-reply@mydomain.com>". When an employer receives the email from the candidate and responds to it by reply, it sends an email directly to candidate's inbox (which is working absolutely fine). But the problem is when the employer has set up an automated-reply email, it sends to my email address "no-reply@mydomain.com" and candidate doesn't receive anything from the employer. Not sure, why automated-reply ignore the candidate email. Please help me on this.

**I am using following plugins:**

1. "WP Job Manager" for job listings
2. "Contact Listing for WP Job Manager" for apply job form.

**Below is the Contact Form7 setup sreenshot**

[image]

**And this is what employer receive**

[image]

And here is the code of the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Your Name *</label>
    [text* your-name class:form-control] 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Your Email *</label>
    [email* your-email class:form-control]
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Application Subject *</label>
    [text* your-subject class:form-control placeholder "Ex: Applying For Accountant"]
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Application Cover Letter</label>
    [textarea your-message class:form-control maxlength:500]
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label> Upload Resume</label> <em style="font-size: 12px;">( pdf, doc, docx )</em>
    [file upload-file limit:2mb filetypes:pdf|doc|docx class:form-control]
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    [submit "Send"]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Mail(2) section for auto responder to work. Here is the official documentation [Autoresponder setup for contact form 7](http://jordiplana.com/contact-form-7-autoresponder-setup)

Although you can follow below step:

1. Scroll down on your contact page and you will see Mail(2) section.
2. Select Use Mail checkbox and then copy email shortcode [your-email] and paste it into To textbox. We need this shortcode to send autoresponders.
3. This [your-email] shortcode will catch users email which he will enter in email box while submitting a contact form.
4. Then enter your message which you want to send via autoresponder and then click on save button. Now your autoresponder is setup.

Below image for your reference

[image]

Comment: I think you didn't get what I said.